Exception on ShowDialog a secondary WinForm
I'm finishing a project of a WinForm App.
The project it compiles but when I try to show a secondary WinForm I get an exception.
The WinForm has some TextBoxes that has their text properties defined in My.Settings
I'm showing the secondary WinForm with this line
ConfigForm.ShowDialog()

And the exception says: System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind Forward_Port property or column in DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember'

You are asking about two completely unrelated issues. Edit your question to ask a single question about one issue. If the issue with the Properties window is resolved, I suggest that you remove any reference to it in this question, including in the title. You also need to provide more information about the run-time exception.

@jmcilhinney I thought that they was related but I will edit it. What info do you need about the exception?

The stack trace would be good. I would also think that you would know where you're using a Forward_Port property or column in data binding, so you should be able to investigate where you're trying to bind it yourself initially. The binding may be happening in the Load event handler but, if you're using the default instance in that one line of code you posted, it may be happening in the constructor, which would suggest that you have set up binding in the designer. From that perspective, maybe there was some relation to the designer issue but I wouldn't think so.

See the first part of this post.  Set the necessary property values in the constructor for the secondary form (remove the default constructor). Retrieve the values in the main form. When you create a new instance of the secondary form, pass the values that you retrieved.

@jmcilhinney There's no Stacktrace, the issue is not in my code. Something got wrong with the code that Visual Studio generate to link the App setting to the text of the TextBox.

Try creating a new project and test if the problem is prevalent to determine if the problem is with Visual Studio or if it's specific to your project.

@JiachenLi-MSFT I solved, I unbond it from My.Settings and bond it back again.
